# Powershell using Add-ADGroupMember throwing error

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm using the following code to try to remove & add users to ActiveDirectory groups:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

$logs = "D:\logs"
$user = "TempValue"
$group = Get-ADGroup "SomeValue"
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$userPrincipal = (get-aduser "$user" -server 123 -properties *).userPrincipalName
$newUser = (get-aduser -filter "userPrincipalName -like '$userPrincipal'" -server 456)

$FileSystem = New-Object -com "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$stream = $FileSystem.CreateTextFile("$logs\changedgroups-$date.txt", $True, $True)

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "$group" -Member "$user" -Confirm:$false
$stream.WriteLine("Removed $user from $group")
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -server 123 -Member $newUser
$stream.WriteLine("Added $newUser to $group")
```

**Scenario:** <strike>Both domains are in the same forest</strike> Domains are in separate forests. I'm on domain "123" trying to remove a user from a group in domain 123 and add a user to that same group from domain 456.

**Problem:** It adds the user from domain 456, but it shows the user as a Foreign Security policy and gives the message "Note that this object is just a placeholder for a user or group from a trusted external domain." Any idea why?

Comment: comment sections from this post is helpful https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2010/01/20/addingremoving-members-from-another-forest-or-domain-to-groups-in-active-directory/

Comment: I tried using the Set-ADObject cmdlet as well to no avail, PS would throw error "specified account does not exist".

Comment: [Maybe related](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/foreign_groupmembers.shtml).

Comment: with FQDN `Get-ADUser user -Server 123.domain.com` ?

Comment: Correct. I was using FQDNs.

Comment: its working for me i tested on one of my client we have trust relation setup i test a user from abc domain to def domain i was able to add, remove from groups no issues

http://imgur.com/a/jfm5I

Comment: @Owl - I'm using  the same Set-ADObject method as described in the comments, but using Add instead of Remove. When I do, I receive this error: http://imgur.com/dtZ1uUQ.

Comment: Does `123` host the global catalog? What are your operating system versions? What are the domain and forest functional levels?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - 123 does host the global catalog. The operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2. Domain functional: Windows Server 2008 R2. Forest functional: Windows Server 2003

Comment: For the external domain as well?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - yes, both domain & forest functional are the same for both domains. The operating system for 456 DC is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: **Edit:** Domains are in different forests. Not sure if that makes too much of a difference.

Comment: Are AD Web Services installed on all relevant DCs and accessible from the DCs of the opposite domain/forest? There is a two-way trust between both forests (or at least domains), correct?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I believe AD Web Services are installed, but I can't access the DCs to check. However, I do know that there is a two-way trust between the forests.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this limitation of add-adgroupmember as well. To get around it switch to Set-ADGroup a few examples are provided below. You can specify the DN,SID or samaccountname withing the add or remove

```
Set-ADGroup -Add:@{'Member'="CN=Group3,CN=Users,DC=GLOBOMANTICS,DC=COM"} -Identity:"CN=Group1,CN=Users,DC=GLOBOMANTICS,DC=COM" -Server:"DC.GLOBOMANTICS.COM"

Set-ADGroup -Identity:"CN=Group1,CN=Users,DC=GLOBOMANTICS,DC=COM" -Remove:@{'Member'="CN=Group3,CN=Users,DC=GLOBOMANTICS,DC=COM"} -Server:"DC.GLOBOMANTICS.COM"
```

Comment: Just saw that you said you used set-adgroup did you specify credentials for that domain? try using the DN or SID something very specific to that domain and object.

Comment: I got the error "An internal error occured" using Set-ADGroup. :/